# Los datos que ingreso en mi formulario no se están enviando

Tags: javascript, html5, mvc

Estoy tomando los datos de mi formulario mediante

```
document.getElementById("idFormulario").value;
```

y tengo una función que permite enviar dichos datos, pero al momento de presionar el botón que llama a dicha función los datos no se toman desde mi furmulario.

Mi estructura está así, pongo como ejemplo un campo de mi formulario,

***html***:

```
  <form method=post id="frmConfig" name="frmConfig" novalidate>
      <div>
          <label class="labelbill">  Fecha de Emisión: </label> 
          <input id = "date" class="inputbill" type="date" style="size: 10%"
                            placeholder="Fecha">
      </div>
      <div>
          <label class="labelbill" style="margin-right: 89px">Establecimiento:</label>
          <input id = "establishment" class="inputbill" type="text" style="size: 10%" placeholder="001-002">
      </div>
      <div>
          <label class="labelbill">Guía de Remisión:</label> 
          <input id = "remission" class="inputbill" type="text" style="size: 10%" placeholder="001-001-123456789">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
         <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><i class="fa fa-users fa-lg fa-fw"></i>Cliente</li>
         </ol>
      </div>
      <div>
         <label class="labelbill">Tipo de Identificación: </label> 
         <select id ="identifications" name ="identifications" data-ng-click = "cambiar()" required >
             <option value="0">--</option>
             <option value="1">RUC</option> 
             <option value="2">CEDULA DE IDENTIDAD</option>
             <option value="3">PASAPORTE</option>  
         </select>
      </div>
      <div>
          <label class="labelbill" style="margin-right:110px">Identificación:</label> 
          <input id = "identification" class="inputbill" type="text" style="size: 10%" placeholder="Identificación">
      </div>                        
      <div>
           <label class="labelbill" style="margin-right: 117px">Razón Social:</label> 
           <input id = "businessName" class="inputbill" type="text" style="size: 10%" placeholder="Razón Social">
      </div>
      <div>
          <label class="labelbill" style="margin-right: 135px">Dirección:</label> 
          <input id="direction" class="inputbill" type="text" style="size: 10%" placeholder="Dirección">
      </div>
      <div>
          <label class="labelbill" style="margin-right: 140px">Teléfono:</label>    
          <input class="inputbill" type="text" style="size: 10%" placeholder="Teléfono">
      </div>
      <div>
          <label class="labelbill" style="margin-right: 82px">Correo Electrónco:</label> 
         <input id="email" class="inputbill" type="text" style="size: 10%"
                            placeholder="Correo Electrónco">
                      </div>
                    <div id = "producto">
                      <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <li><i class="fa fa-users fa-lg fa-fw"></i>Producto</li>
                            <li><a href="/#myModalCreate" data-toggle="modal"
                                class="btn btn-primary"  style="position: relative; margin-bottom: 4px;">Añadir Producto</a>
                                <jsp:include page="addproduct.jsp" flush="false" /></li>
                        </ol>

                    </div>
                    <table
                        class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover table-sm">
                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-center"><i></i>Cantidad</th>
                                <th class="text-center"><i></i>Descripción</th>
                                <th class="text-center"><i></i>Precio Unitario</th>
                                <th class="text-center"><i></i>Descuento</th>
                                <th class="text-center"><i></i>Tarifa</th>
                                <th class="text-center"><i></i>ICE</th>
                                <th class="text-center"><i></i>Precio SubTotal</th>

                            </tr>
                            <tbody id = "tabla_proucto">                            
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div id = "formaPago">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <li><i class="fa fa-users fa-lg fa-fw"></i>Formas de pago</li>
                            <li><a id = "btnaddwaytopay" href="/#addWayToPay" data-toggle="modal"
                                class="btn btn-primary" style="position: relative; margin-bottom: 4px;">Añadir forma de pago</a>
                                <jsp:include page="addwaytopay.jsp" flush="false" /></li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                    <table
                        class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover table-sm">

                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-center"><i></i>Forma de Pago</th>
                                <th class="text-center"><i></i>Valor</th>
                                <th class="text-center"><i></i>Plazo</th>
                                <th class="text-center"><i></i>Tiempo</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr data-ng-if="result.length == 0">
                                <td colspan="6">Tabla vacía</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tbody id = "tabla_forma_pago">     
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                    <div id = "infoAdicional">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <li><i class="fa fa-users fa-lg fa-fw"></i>Informacion adicional</li>
                            <li><a id = "btnInfoAdicional" data-toggle="modal"
                                class="btn btn-primary" style="position: relative; margin-bottom: 4px;" data-ng-click="mostrarTabla()">Añadir Información Adicional</a>
                                </li>
                        </ol>

                    <table
                        class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                            <th ><i></i>Información adicional</th>
                                <th ><i></i>Valor </th>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> <input id = "textInfoAd"
                            class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Información"> </td> 
                                <td> <input id = "valorInfoAd"
                            class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Valor"> </td> 
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <div class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="addInfoAd()">Guardar</div>
                                    <div class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</div></td>
                            </tr>                       
                        </tbody>
                    </table>


                    </div>

                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div id = "total">
                      <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <li><i class="fa fa-users fa-lg fa-fw"></i>Totales</li>
                            <li><a data-toggle="modal"
                                class="btn btn-primary"  style="position: relative; margin-bottom: 4px;" data-ng-click="calcularTotal()">Calcular</a>
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                    <table
                        class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover table-sm">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th class=""><i></i>Subtotal 12% </th>
                                <th class=""><i></i>{{sumaTarifasDoce}}</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class=""><i></i>Subtotal 0%</th>
                                <th class=""><i></i>{{sumaTarifasCero}}</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class=""><i></i>Subtotal no objeto de IVA</th>
                                <th class=""><i></i>{{sumaNoObjImp}}</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class=""><i></i>Subtotal exento de IVA</th>
                                <th class=""><i></i>{{sumaExentoIva}}</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class=""><i></i>Subtotal sin impuestos</th>
                                <th class=""><i></i>{{sumaSubTotales}}</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class=""><i></i>Total descuento</th>
                                <th class=""><i></i>{{totalDescuentos}}</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class=""><i></i>ICE</th>
                                <th class=""><i></i>{{valorIce}}</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="" id = "Iva"><i></i>IVA 12%</th>
                                <th class=""><i></i>{{tarifaDoceSubtotal}}</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class=""><i></i>Propina</th>
                                <th class=""><i></i>0</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="" id = "Total"><i></i>VALOR TOTAL</th>
                                <th class=""><i></i>{{totalFact}}</th>
                            </tr>   
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
                                    data-ng-click="enviar()">Enviar</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn btn-danger"
                                    onclick="location.reload()"
                                    data-ng-disabled="frmConfig.$invalid">Cancelar</button> <br> <br>               
                    </div>
</form>
```

***js***:

```
    info= new Object()
    info.identificacionComprador = document.getElementById("establishment").value;
    $scope.enviar = function() {

        var myString = JSON.stringify(info);

        var sendJSON = billService.sendFile(myString)
    }
```

Pero al presionar el botón enviar lo que ingresé en el formulario nunca se carga, eso ¿por qué se da?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Que seria esto? `document.getElementById("identification").value;` no deberías recoger el valor de tu input con id establishment

Comment: Gracias por la observación, he editado el código.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar todo el código del formulario?

Comment: he añadido el código, pero no sé por qué no se muestra la parte de Fecha de Emisión: Establecimiento: Guía de Remisión:

Cliente
Tipo de Identificación: -- RUC CEDULA DE IDENTIDAD PASAPORTE: <label class="labelbill">Fecha de Emisión:</label> <label class="labelbill" style="margin-right: 89px">Establecimiento:</label>

Comment: ya esta editado espera que lo aprueben !!

Comment: Intenta cambiar todas las propiedades `id` de tu formulario por `name`

Comment: @alanfcm eso no resultó efectivo, lo que hice fue dentro de mi función agregar las llamadas a los valores de los tags. con eso la información si se toma. Gracias.